# Does a Microcomputer consist of a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller

I know what a microcomputer is, but is it's CPU a microcontroller or a microprocessor?

Comment: Is there anything *factual* you wanted to know that isn't a matter of definition?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

microprocessor. DRAM, bootprom, etc on external buss vs internal to the chip.